# prototype error for function defined in the header file

Tags: c++, overloading

I came to this strange `error : prototype for ‘void Table::add(E)’ does not match any in class ‘Table’`. I know that this error is when the function isn't defined in the class body or defined with wrong arguments or return type but this is not my case.

The `add` function is defined in the header file. The strange thing is when I comment the other functions (remove, print) gcc doesn't complain about it.
Here's my code:

**table.hpp**

```
class Table {
    private:

    public:
    Table(int size=100);
    Table(Table& t);
    ~Table();

    void print();
    void add(string name, string num);
    void add(E e);
    void remove(string name, string num);
    string to_string();

    /* some function definitions and operators */
};
```

**table.cpp**

```
void Table::add(E e){
    if (size == nb_elem)
        cout << "Error";
    else
        t[nb_elem++] = e;
}

void Table::add(string name, string num) {
    E e(name, num);
    this->add(e); //this->add(E(name, num);
}
```

**Note**

I'm a learning C++ language.

Comment: Please provide buildable code.  What is the declaration of t used in add(E)

Comment: In fact gcc created .ghc file and has a outdated information

Comment: Please post a complete yet minimal example program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I solved my problem look at the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking at project files I have found a file `table.hpp.ghc` and my problem is exactly as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241399/what-is-a-h-gch-file). I solved my problem by removing this file.

I don't know why gcc created it.