# Compilation error: `error: definition of implicitly-declared`

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a class which calls one of it's functions when created, but I am getting the following error when compiling:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors -DNDEBUG -c src/PuzzleSolution.cpp
src/PuzzleSolution.cpp:7:32: error: definition of implicitly-declared 'PuzzleSolution::PuzzleSolution()'
 PuzzleSolution::PuzzleSolution()
                                ^
src/PuzzleSolution.cpp:12:6: error: prototype for 'void PuzzleSolution::addRow()' does not match any in class 'PuzzleSolution'
 void PuzzleSolution::addRow()
      ^
src/PuzzleSolution.h:19:10: error: candidate is: void PuzzleSolution::addRow(std::vector<unsigned int>&)
     explicit PuzzleSolution();
          ^
src/PuzzleSolution.cpp:17:48: error: no 'void PuzzleSolution::addElement(unsigned int)' member function declared in class 'PuzzleSolution'
 void PuzzleSolution::addElement(unsigned int id)
                                                ^
make: *** [PuzzleSolution.o] Error 1
```

Here is the header:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class PuzzleSolution {
private:
    vector<vector<unsigned int>> sol;

public:
    explicit PuzzleSolution();

    void addRow();
};
```

Here is the cpp file:

```
#include "PuzzleSolution.h"

PuzzleSolution::PuzzleSolution()
{
    addRow();
}

void PuzzleSolution::addRow()
{
    this->sol.emplace_back();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No idea. [Your code builds as is on GCC 7.2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0b3282021c70176)

Comment: I am using g++-4.8.2 I think. I have to build and make it work on a specific machine @StoryTeller

Comment: You seem to be compiling with another header defining `PuzzleSolution`. The errors make no sense with the header you've given here.

Comment: [It builds on GCC 4.8.4 too](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lVizXOHMnzst7hiJ)

Comment: I agree @ArkadiuszKoćma, but it's not my choice

Comment: @Quentin could it be an issue with the compiler I am using? it's a university server which I have no control over...

Comment: Actually, there's one difference between the code I used to test and yours. I dropped the `using namespace std;`. Probably not realted, but give it a go.

Comment: @TomerAmir make sure that you saved your changes to `PuzzleSolution.h` and that there are no duplicates of this file lying around.

Comment: Found the issue... I don't know why, but there were two files in the same folder called: `PuzzleSolution.h.gch` and `PuzzleSolution.h~`. Once I removed them, the issue got fixed... @Quentin

Comment: @TomerAmir alright, `PuzzleSolution.h~` is typically a backup file from your text editor and is harmless. `PuzzleSolution.h.gch`, however, is a [precompiled header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241399/what-is-a-h-gch-file), which was used instead of the "vanilla" header you were editig. Precompiled headers are neat, but you have to remember to rebuild them when changes are made :)

Comment: Thanks Quentin and StroyTeller!
I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue:

There was a file in the `src` folder called `PuzzleSolution.h.gch`

@Quatin and @StoryTeller helped me to understand that this is a pre-compiled header, which the compiler kept using.

Once deleted, the project compiled and executed

Answer (score 0):

The code as it is has no error. It compiles with GCC 4.8.2

Be sure that your header file is indeed what you have linked to. Most likely the header being included is different than the one you have actually posted here.

Side Note: Generally it is considered as a bad practice to put `using namespace std;` in a header file.

Comment: There obviously is a problem, or the OP wouldn't be posting. So saying "there's no error" is comment material, not answer material.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, but I found the issue and posted an answer